# Batch checking the VM status with Softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using Softlayer APIs to check the status of the VMs we create. Below are the APIs we are using now, and we have to check the status for one VM at a time. Is there a Softlayer API that can retrieve the status of a list of VMs?

Here are the APIs we are calling to get the status of one VM each time:
1. Get the VM id
api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/findByIpAddress/*x.x.x.x*
2. Get the VM status
api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/*vmID*/getPowerState.json

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no api method to get those values, but they are:

**Power State:**

- Running
- Halted
- Paused
- Suspended
- Unknown

**Status**

- Id: 1001 - Active
- Id: 1002 - Disabled
- Id: 1003 - Inactive
- Id: 1004 - Deleted
- Id: 1006 - Disconnected

Answer (score 0):

**To get the VM status from all your virtual servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[powerState]

Method: Get
```

Note: Replace **$user** and **$apiKey** with your own information

---

**To get the VM status from a list:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[powerState]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"id":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":[$vsiId1, $vsiId2, $vsiId3]}]}}}

Method: Get
```

Note: Replace **$user**, **$apiKey**, **$vsiId1**, **$vsiId2**, **$vsiId3** with your own information, you can add more ids, separating by ","

---

> **Updated**

### cURL

If you are using curl, you should send the command encoded, because we are using filters in the request, so it should look like this:

```
curl "https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask%5BpowerState%5D&objectFilter=%7B%22virtualGuests%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22in%22%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22data%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B25129322%2C15535999%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D"
```

**Replace**: $user, $apiKey, 25129322 and 15535999 with you own information

The VSI identifiers that I'm looking for are: 25129322 and 15535999, as you can see, they are encoded in the command

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. A few things to confirm:

* For the first API call, does it return status for all the VMs that were created using the same Softlayer userid and apikey, or all the VMs that are in the same account?

Comment: * For the first API call, when I pass "objectMask=mask" it works, but when I add something after mask[attribute], the call failed. I tried to follow the format described in http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks, but it did not help.
curl --user $user:$apikey -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[powerState]"
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 86

* I have not got luck with the second API call yet, got errors.

Comment: The first request will retrieve all virtual servers from your account

Comment: For your second question, see the **Updated** section in my answer please

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I thought by specifying objectMask=mask[powerState] would limit the attributes returned, but it is not the case for me. Can you please comment?

Comment: I also posted a question above regarding the powerState and status attributes, can you please comment?

Comment: You can limit or extend the response using ObjectMask, to get more information about this review: [Object Masks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks)