# Softlayer's Virtual Server status Ids

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Looks like Softlayer's API has changed the way its checked the status of a Virtual Server. Taking a looks at the docs, now when I get VS attributes the response looks like this REST example http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

Taking a look at the specification in http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest seems like the state is returned in a new "statusId" attribute, but when I try to access to the docs of that attribute, it shows nothing http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Status

Do you know where I can get a list of statusIds for a VS?
I've checked that a running VS returns 1001 and a cancelled one 1006. When the VS is removed, you get 404 HTTP status code.

Note: this question is trying to target Softlayer's development team, as suggested in my support request.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to retrieve a list of status for VSIs, but you can take a look this forum, in which I provide information about them (Status and Power State)

- [Batch checking the VM status with Softlayer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272343/batch-checking-the-vm-status-with-softlayer-api)